# a question about the angles between the diagonals of a trapezoid.

Tags: euclidean-geometry

We have a trapezoid with bases $4$ and $9$, and diagonals $5$ and $12$. 
Determine the area of it and also the angle between the diagonals.
The area is $15\sqrt{2}$; with cosine formula it is $90$ degrees, but I don't want to use it.

I have done every strategy I knew!

It will be great if you check it and help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you saw, the Cosine Law tells us the angle. Let us see whether we can avoid the Cosine Law and use a more geometric approach.

Imagine the trapezoid in standard position, bottom side $9$, top side $4$.  Now look at the top triangle and bottom triangle. They are similar, so the sides of the top triangle are $4\cdot \frac{5}{13}$ and $4\cdot \frac{12}{13}$. It follows (converse of Pythagorean Theorem) that the angle between the diagonals is $90$ degrees.